# OpenCV, долго включается камера и создаётся окно с выводом видеопотока

Tags: python, opencv

Собственно, вопрос в названии.
Код выглядит так:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    frame = cam.read()[1]
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Версия модуля 4.5.5.62 (для подсказок, на версиях выше ничего не меняется)
python 3.11
Дополнительно: можно ли как то сделать изображение с камеры более чётким?

Comment: посмотрите что возвращает `cam.getBackendName()` и лучше переключитесь на соответствующий SDK, ну или попробуйте покрутить `VideoCaptureProperties`

Answer (score 0):

***OpenCV, долго включается камера***

Такое может произойти при использовании USB камер. Т.е., встроенная камера ноутбука откликнется быстрее, чем USB камера.

***Можно ли как то сделать изображение с камеры более чётким?***

Если стоит задача получения высоко- качественного изображения, то начинать надо с выбора хорошей высокоскоростной камеры. Например, комплект USB-камеры **Arducam 12MP**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]